# How to read a file based on string position and store it in variable

Tags: java, string, file-io

I need to read a file, completely and split the strings inside the file and store it in a variable using Java

See below example, my text file contains

```
devarajan        1000210         08754540275     600019      
ramesh           1000210         08754540275     600019      
udhay            1000210         08754540275     600019
```

I tired using string position but it is not working out.

Please find attached sample file as well. Regards

My Code:

```
public class Program { 
     public static void main(String[] args) { 
        String line = "devarajan 1000210 08754540275 600019 "; 
        String[] words = line.split("\\W+"); 
        for (String word : words) {
                   System.out.println(word); 
                                  } 
                             }
                       }
```

Output:

```
devarajan 1000210 08754540276
```

My file will contain the list of string 10-10 position will be name 20-30 position will be empid 30-40 will phone number. so while i used the previous snippet i am getting blank spaces "devarajan" "   1000210".. i should avoid that blank spaces.

In turn my code is splitting up as soon as it encounters blank space, instead of position
@Twelve, @ Kick : I am getting the output as follows for your snippet 
but imagine if i have a space in my name ex: "twelve dollar" instead of "
twelvedollar", then the name will get split and stored in different array position. and that is the reason, i have asked whether it is possible to split the string based on the position

Comment: show your code snippet!!! than we can help you out

Comment: Regular expression time :-) Show the code, and we'll help.

Comment: [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/), [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) or [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), then store them in an [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) and/or some kind of `List` or other [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Comment: I am new to java, i tried a standalone java with sample string it worked.. but while reading a file fully and splitting it, i do not know. :(

Comment: we totally trust you, but you need to show what you have done and what exactly is troubling you. as a coder, you should be more specific about what is going on your world.

Comment: Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("directory"); Then make calls to input with input.nextLine(), input.next(), and all the other related "next" commands. Use Integer.parseInt() as well. indexOf(' ') may help too

Comment: public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

 String line = "devarajan        1000210         08754540275     600019    ";

 
 String[] words = line.split("\\W+");

 
 
 for (String word : words) {
     System.out.println(word);
 }
    }
}

This give a output like

devarajan 



1000210



08754540276

Comment: public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

 String line = "devarajan        1000210         08754540275     600019    ";

 
 String[] words = line.split("\\W+");

 
 
 for (String word : words) {
     System.out.println(word);
 }
    }
}

This give a output like

devarajan 



1000210



08754540276 but my file will contain, 1-10 psotion will be name 10-20 phone number 20-30 empid, so my prgoram should ignore the spaced in between  and read exactly from that position

Comment: @DevarajanCM I updated your post right now. what is your issue? it seems you are almost right about what you try to do .

Comment: Thank you @Kick Buttowski, i Just edited with my updated query. Thanks for helping me in editing the post

Comment: @KickButtowski : This gives a solution to split up the strings, bbut what is happening is that, if the name Kick Buttowski has space in between, it is getting splitted. so that why i need to split the strings by position

Answer (score 0):

just one way to do it ..

```
try {
  Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("myInputFile.txt"));
  String[] data;
  ArrayList<String[]> arr = new ArrayList<String[]>();
  while (inFile.hasNext()) {
    data = inFile.nextLine().split("\\s+"); // or split("\t") if using tabs
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
    arr.add(data);
  }
}

catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
  fe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what your problem really is now

Comment: This will work out and you will store the entire string in an array but the problem is                                                                       
devarajan   1000210    08754540275   600019
ramesh       1000210    08754540275   600019
udhay         1000210    08754540275   600019   
In my example Name will start 0th position and ends in 20th position. Emp id will starts from 20-30 and so on.. And i need to store name separately in an array

Comment: no not the entire string is stored in an array. data[0] contains name, data[1] first number and so on ...

Comment: @ Kick : I am getting the output as follows for your snippet 
but image if i have a space in my name ex: twelve dollar instead of twelvedollar, then the name will get split and stored in different array position. and that is the reason, i have asked whether it is possible to split the string based on the position